# Document Reminder Emails from Case

Tags: apex, administration, automation, send-email

On the Case object I have several flags:
"Annex D"
"Proof of Ownership"
"MPAN"
"Annex I"
"Company Car"
"Documents Uploaded" etc.
Each flag is getting checked when the corresponding document get uploaded in Salesforce, Now I want to send first email template after 24 hours when Opportunity becomes "Qualified", also want to send next email template after a specific time(48 hours) after the first email template based on flag checks.

I think we can implement this with below features:

1.Process Builder: 
         Scheduling is supporting only "When the record is created".So can't use this one.

2.Workflow: There are multiple conditions for sending a single email based on the flag check, having multiple email templates for the different conditions, I think need to create lots of workflow rules and it'll be unmanageable.

3.Apex: Confused over here which option is better to implement this requirement, If Apex Trigger is the best option, Can anybody help me how to implement this using apex..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have separate datetime fields for each time based action you want to trigger. 
For example,when ever the opportunity becomes qualified update a datetime field called QualifedDate__c ( using workflow field update ).
You can then trigger a process builder ( over the record update ) to trigger a time based action to send an email.

Comment: Process builder supports to schedule an action only when "The record is created". Schedule action is not available on "Created and every time it's updated" at the object level criteria(when you select an object in the process). So we can't use process builder over here.

Comment: @Nilesh Please take a look at this screen shot - http://d.pr/i/wACM0G. There is an option to select -> when a record is created or edited.

Comment: I can see the option for "Created and every time it's edited" but the option for scheduling an action(Schedule action) through the process is not available with this criteria.

Comment: @Nilesh - see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240371&type=1